# Bundler: how to use without rails?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a project using cucumber outside of rails. How can I load the gems with the versions specified in my gemfile?

Answer (score 26):

Digging through [the Bundler website](http://bundler.io/):

1. Create `Gemfile` (run `bundle init` to create skeleton `Gemfile`)
2. `bundle install`
3. In your app:

   ```
   # Only needed for ruby 1.8.x
   require 'rubygems'

   # The part that activates bundler in your app
   require 'bundler/setup' 

   # require your gems as usual
   require 'some_gem'

   # ...or require all the gems in one statement
   Bundler.require
   ```

#### Could be worth checking out:

[Bundler.io - Using Bundler in Your Appplication](http://bundler.io/v1.12/guides/using_bundler_in_application.html)
[Bundler.io - Bundler.setup and Bundler.require](http://bundler.io/v1.12/bundler_setup.html)

[Are bundle exec and require 'bundler/setup' equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117112/are-bundle-exec-and-require-bundler-setup-equivalent)

Answer (score 11):

I just learned about a way to make Bundler automatically require dependencies from a Gemfile.  Add this code at the beginning of a Ruby program that has a Gemfile:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require
```

With Bundler.require there's no need to explicitly require the gems/libraries enumerated in the Gemfile.

This solution is from http://technotales.wordpress.com/2010/08/22/bundler-without-rails/

To be honest I'm not sure if the require rubygems part is needed either.

Comment: `require 'rubygems'` is only needed with Ruby prior to 1.8.7, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the simplest and most straightforward approach:

1. `bundler init` will create the Gemfile for you
2. Specify gems in the Gemfile.
3. Add the following to your main Ruby file

```
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require
```

4. Run `bundler install` to install the gems.

More information can (now) be found at http://bundler.io.

Answer (score 2):

Casper has a pretty good answer (despite some passive aggressiveness) but I think the missing piece for you is `bundle exec`. When you run the `$ rails ...` commands on the command line, Rails uses bundler to load those dependencies/gems. Rake, for example, doesn't by default so in order to run `rake test` using an older version of cucumber than what is on your system, you have to use `bundle exec rake test`. It's a good habit to get into *always* using `$ bundle exec ...` when you're using Bundler — it's explicit, you're always sure you're using the right gems, and it ensures you don't forget to add a dependency to your Gemfile (i.e. you push to another server or another developer and they are having issues because you didn't note the need for something you use but they don't).

Comment: Yeah..I guess a friendly tongue in cheek doesn't come through the internet too well :-/ Fixed. Is `bundle exec` needed even if you `require "bundler/setup"`. I.e. is `bundle exec` there just to insure it works even without the setup?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with integrating Bundler into the app — I know you can just run `$ bundle exec ruby foo.rb` and you are set.

Comment: Ok thanks. In fact I just looked at the [bundle exec docs](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-exec.1.html), and it seems to indeed "force" an explicit `bundler/setup` into ruby upon execution (among other things). So using `bundle exec` is a kind of extra insurance that everything will really be run with bundler. It also makes it easy to bundlerize old apps (or any apps) this way, and you won't need to necessarily touch any code.