# Git Multi-Project files

Tags: git, bitbucket

I've started to use git to keep track of some of my scripts that are used across several projects. I don't have the complete projects on git, just the multi-project files. I'm trying to get these files from git and have them update local instances of the file across the different projects.

For example: One of my scripts is a JavaScript InputManager. This manager gets changed and updated in all different projects I'm working on, but all of them should have the latest version.

Is there any way to retrieve the latest version of the InputManager from git and update that version so it gets updated in my other projects too?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one local repository where you do your changes. (And probably another "official" one where you push your changes to.)

All your project contain another clone of the repository. If you want to update such a repository you have to do a `git pull` in each of them.

Answer (score 0):

One options is to turn them into gems and use bundler in the other projects to pull the gem in.

Making gems:  http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/

Using bundler outside of rails:

http://technotales.wordpress.com/2010/08/22/bundler-without-rails/

[Bundler: how to use without rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999547/bundler-how-to-use-without-rails)

Bundler itself: http://bundler.io/

n.b. I don't normally post so many links but in this case the first line of my answer kinda says it all and can be regoogled.